# How to find the phase of this transfer function?

Tags: control, control-system, transfer-function, phase

I have been trying to find the phase of this transfer function:

G(jω)H(jω)=0.1695/jω(5.88jω+1)

by doing this:

Phase = -arctan(0/0.1695)-arctan(w/-5.88*w^2)

PHASE = 0-arctan(1/-5.88*w)

Is this correct ? since for some reason the result does not make sense.

[image]

Comment: Show your working - it looks like your answer is incorrect because it doesn't include 0.1695 unless your calcs are very sloppy.

Comment: @Andyaka 0.1695 doesn't make a difference to phase. A constant has no phase, last time I checked

Comment: OK, sorry. I just re-read your equation but, you should still show your workings. Yes, that final phase formula looks correct but show your workings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the OP adds his own work, this gives the final answer.

A general transfer function with \$\exists\alpha\space\wedge\space\exists\beta\space\wedge\space\exists\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^+\$ is given by:

$$\mathcal{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\alpha}{\text{s}\left(\beta\text{s}+\gamma\right)}\tag1$$

When dealing with sinusoids we know that \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$. So we get:

$$\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\underline{\text{Y}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}{\underline{\text{X}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}=\frac{\alpha}{\text{j}\omega\left(\text{j}\omega\beta+\gamma\right)}\tag2$$

Now, we know:

$$\text{j}\omega\left(\text{j}\omega\beta+\gamma\right)=\text{j}\omega\text{j}\omega\beta+\text{j}\omega\gamma=\text{j}\omega\gamma-\omega^2\beta\tag3$$

When dealing with the argument of the transfer function, we get:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\arg\left(\frac{\underline{\text{Y}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}{\underline{\text{X}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Y}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{X}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(\frac{\alpha}{\text{j}\omega\left(\text{j}\omega\beta+\gamma\right)}\right)=\arg\left(\alpha\right)-\arg\left(\text{j}\omega\left(\text{j}\omega\beta+\gamma\right)\right)=$$
$$\arg\left(\alpha\right)-\arg\left(\text{j}\omega\gamma-\omega^2\beta\right)=0-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\omega^2\beta}{\omega\gamma}\right)\right)=$$
$$-\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\beta}{\gamma}\right)\tag4$$

---

In your case we have \$\alpha=0.1695\$, \$\beta=5.88\$ and \$\gamma=1\$. So we get:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=-\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{5.88\omega}{1}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(5.88\omega\right)\tag5$$

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I am doing ? Sorry I cant find my mistake

Comment: @SamwelPortelli you didn't show your work so I do not know where you went wrong. But I think that the value of \$\beta>0\$.

Comment: I added my method, what do you think ?

Comment: @SamwelPortelli See my edit.

Comment: Jan, I tried this formula and it is also giving me incorrect result. The result of the phase should follow the bode plot I uploaded now in my edit

Comment: As you can see the phase should go from -86 to -180 (in this range of frequency). Using your formula it is giving me a phase of approx. 90 deg for every frequency

Comment: @SamwelPortelli well when \$\omega=0\$ we get an argument of \$-\frac{\pi}{2}\$ which implies \$-90^\circ\$.

Comment: @SamwelPortelli And when \$\omega\to\infty\$ we get an argument of \$-\pi\$ which implies \$-180^\circ\$

Comment: @SamwelPortelli And this exactly is what you have plotted in your question.

Comment: OMG, I cant belive what my mistake is.... I my calculator is set to work in radians and I wrote 90deg

Comment: Thanks jan for all the trouble

Comment: @SamwelPortelli ;) Classic mistake, it is okay, just a good learning point! I am glad that I could be of any help. You can vote up and close the question by accepting my answer.